# Video add in Html not sync with Github

Tags: html, github, html5-video

I have added a Video file in Html and it works perfectly but how can I sync with GitHub?

Github rejects big files, the file size is 470 MB.

How can I link it? Any alternative methods?

My code:

```
    <video class="w-100" muted autoplay loop>
    <source src="./assets/video/ap-intro.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

Please Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also encountered a similar issue. You can upload the 'Assets' folder to the remote Git server using Git LFS (Large File Storage), but there are certain permissions that need to be enabled on the remote server. You can find detailed instructions at https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/INSTALLING.md.

Comment: Git LFS (Large File Storage) is awesome thank you. It really helped me.